# Sliding Menu and Horizontal ScrollView in Android

Tags: android, swipe, horizontalscrollview, slidingmenu

In my app I have used [Sliding Menu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) by jfeinstein10 and its working fine. Now, according to requirements I have to have a Horizontal ScrollView on a page where this sliding menu can also be opened.

Since this sliding menu opens by swiping left-to-right on any part of the screens, the Horizontal ScrollView isnt working properly with it, as the Sliding Menu consumes the swipe left-to-right before the ScrollView and occupies the screen.

Any one else having encountered the same problem ?

Comment: Any solution till now, MiaN KhaLiD?

Comment: Actually my items in the scrollview reduced. So, I was better off without it.
As of now, the method mentioned by @basilisk in his answer's comments sounds plausible, which is:
"One possible solution might be to extend the CustomViewBehind class, and override onInterceptTouchEvent. If the event coordinates are over your horizontal scroll view, return false, else call super."
I'll give it a try when i get some free time, and will update the thread accordingly :)

Answer (score 3):

you can set the touch mode as margin so the menu will be visible if you swipe from the margin. 
use  `slidingmenu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMOD_MARGIN);`

or in the XML  use  `sliding:touchModeAbove="margin"` 
hope it works.

Comment: Let me try this, but I am more of looking into a solution where touch is first delivered to ScrollView and then to the SlidingMenu (i know i am being vague), but I think this is the key to my problem. And I aint getting anywhere in finding this key as of now :)

Comment: For now I have resorted to your solution Bill, but as I said I am looking for a touch handling or motion event specific solution, so will accept your answer if anyone doesnt give the solution I am looking for. For now I have marked your answer as useful. Thanks again :)

Comment: having the same issue, does anyone have a clue for this?

Comment: @AJit, the method mentioned by basilisk in his answer's comments sounds plausible, which is: "One possible solution might be to extend the CustomViewBehind class, and override onInterceptTouchEvent. If the event coordinates are over your horizontal scroll view, return false, else call super."

Comment: there is a typo in TOUCHMOD_MARGIN, it should be TOUCHMODE_MARGIN :) thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the sliding menu library by the DrawerLayout provided by Google. It only intercepts the touches at the edges of the screen, so you can have a horizontal scroll view as well.

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: Actually I started off with NavigationDrawer but the requirement is allowing user to swipe left-to-right anywhere on the screen and open accordingly. And thats what the native NavigationDrawer lacks. Anyways, thanks for the help btw :)

Comment: One possible solution might be to extend the CustomViewBehind class, and override onInterceptTouchEvent. If the event coordinates are over your horizontal scroll view, return false, else call super.

Comment: ok. I'll look into that as well and will update accordingly :)